# How to achieve a text-muted effect for a label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following label:

```
<label for="name" class="control-label"><h5 class="text-muted">Name</h5></label>.
```

I would like to have a text-muted effect for the label text, but my markup above does not accomplish that.
What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: isn't it better to wrap the `label` with the `h5`? and not the way you did it? By the way. the provieded snippet works with the latest version of bootstrap. http://jsfiddle.net/5aP4p/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am sorry to ask, but what is your CSS of the `.class-muted` ?
Didn't you forget to write the code to the css file?

Here's the working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/2Q2Rz/1/

**Update**

If you are using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 or older, there's no `.text-muted` class, it is `.muted` according to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#typography)

The `.text-muted` class appears  only in Twitter Bootstrap 3